# How to position text right from an image in an unorder list with links

Tags: html, css

It's the second time I have to use `<ul>` to create navigation menu with image and text in each anchor. The first time I managed to do this without fully separating the logic but now it seems a little bit more complicated so I want to solve my current problem and also, to know if there's a general approach to this task since I think it's very common but I'm not able to find clear implementation.

First is the example - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8dUh/1/) as you can see, I have problem with styling/positioning the text in a nice, proper way. What I want is the image(bullet) to stay at the top-left corner as it is right now and I want all text to go right from the image. As you can seen in the first `<li>` when I get certain height the text i going under the image.

For some time now I was thinking about what is the way to make customizeable anchors with image and text. I've had this idea of using two spans so I can have more freedom on styling but as you can see in the example, it's either - me not knowing how ti use `<span>` properly or it's not best suitable for this case. If the text content is too big the text goes under, also the fact that with the margin only the first row is affected.. It seems to me that this is not the right way, so how can I style my anchor list (in this certain example) and is there a more generic way which will allow me to change some things related only to the text or to the image without having to remake the whole structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images that are UI elements should be CSS backgrounds, not inline images. Positioning CSS backgrounds is easy because it doesn't interfere with the contents within the element. It's also better to put all the stylnig on the A-tag (other than positioning), not on the LI.

```
 <li><a href="#">Link<br />12.12.12</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
a.bullet {
     background-image:url(...your image path...);
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     display:block;
     min-width:175px;
     width: 100%;
     min-height:60px;
     padding: (what you want);
     margin: (what you want)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I made a little example and it's really better. Would you take a quick look to say your opinion - http://jsfiddle.net/f8dUh/2/ . By following your answer I think I can get rid of the spans at all?!

Comment: I'd move the LI styling (padding-top: 15px; min-height: 60px;) to your A-tag and give it a bit of padding-right so the text is not right up against the box. Good job.

Comment: Also you can use background-position:0px 0px; to nudge the image around if you want (use your own values - x,y).